# How to show app ad's only to new users?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, applications, ios-appstore

I have an app in the appstore that used to be paid and with no ads.

I want to upload an update, make the app 'free', add ad's, that could be removed by purchasing "No ads 'in-app purchase'".

Problem:

I don't want users that have paid for the app before to update the app and see ads.

I want to grant "No ads 'in-app purchase'" for users who is updating the app.

Basically, if a person is updating, then no ads is 'purchased' by default. 
If a person in downloading the app for the first time, he gets ads.

Is this possible? Any workarounds?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could update the paid app to set a preference that the user has the paid version. Then update the app with the free version.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Do I get it right, If a user skips the first update, he will get the ads anyway?

Comment: @user40 yes, the user will get ads. It was the best I could come up with.